# can't run rspec in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

I'm beginner in RoR, I have an error When I run **rspec** in rails I'm getting this error message:

**You have already activated json 2.0.2, but your Gemfile requires json 1.8.6. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)**

I have tried to update json gem by "**bundle update json**", but still getting the same error message.

Could someone helps me on this.
I'm using:- Ruby 2.3.0
          - Rails 4.2.7.1
          - gem version 2.5.1
**Thank you!**

Here is my Gemfile content:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby "2.3.0"

gem "dhis2",                   github: 'BLSQ/dhis2'
gem "rails",                   "4.2.7.1"
gem "awesome_print",           "1.6.1"
gem "pg",                      "0.18.4"
gem "sass-rails",              "5.0.6"
gem "uglifier",                "3.0.0"
gem "coffee-rails",            "4.1.0"
gem "therubyracer",            "0.12.2"
gem "jquery-rails",            "4.1.1"
gem "translation",             "1.6"
gem "slim",                    "3.0.6"
gem "bootstrap-sass",          "3.3.6"
gem "rails_admin",             "0.8.1"
gem "devise",                  "4.0.0"
gem "simple_form",             "3.2.1"
gem "rest-client",             "2.0.0"
gem "figaro",                  "1.1.1"
gem "sidekiq",                 "4.1.1"
gem "unicorn",                 "5.1.0"
gem "sentry-raven",            "0.15.6"
gem "sinatra",                 require: nil
gem "will_paginate",           "3.1.0"
gem "will_paginate-bootstrap", "1.0.1"
gem "rubyzip", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "axlsx", "2.1.0.pre"
gem "axlsx_rails"
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem "rails4-autocomplete"
gem "chosen-rails"

group :production do
  gem "rails_12factor", "0.0.3"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "derailed"
  gem "byebug"
  gem "database_cleaner"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", " 4.0"
  gem "faker"
  gem "rspec-its"
  gem "rspec-rails",        "~> 3.0"
  gem "shoulda-matchers",   require: false
  gem "rails-erd"
  gem "mailcatcher"
  gem "rest-client-logger"
end

group :development do
  gem "annotate"
  gem "web-console", "2.0"
  gem "spring"
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
  gem 'memory_profiler'
  gem 'flamegraph'
  gem 'stackprof'
end

group :test do
  gem "simplecov", require: false
  gem "codeclimate-test-reporter", "~> 1.0.0"
  gem "webmock"
  gem "rspec-sidekiq",        "~> 2.2.0"

end
```

And Here is Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  revision: d91e3ebecefc3ded8c17d7d786a7de6d42efebfb
  specs:
    dhis2 (2.2.1)
      rest-client

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.7.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.7.1)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.0)
      public_suffix (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.2)
    annotate (2.7.1)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
      rake (>= 10.4, < 12.0)
    arel (6.0.4)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.6.1)
      execjs
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    axlsx (2.1.0.pre)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.1)
      rubyzip (~> 1.1.7)
    axlsx_rails (0.5.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.1)
      axlsx (>= 2.0.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    benchmark-ips (2.7.2)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.6)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (9.0.6)
    choice (0.2.0)
    chosen-rails (1.5.2)
      coffee-rails (>= 3.2)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      sass-rails (>= 3.2)
    codeclimate-test-reporter (1.0.4)
      simplecov
    coffee-rails (4.1.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.4)
    connection_pool (2.2.1)
    crack (0.4.3)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0.0)
    daemons (1.2.4)
    database_cleaner (1.5.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    derailed (0.1.0)
      derailed_benchmarks
    derailed_benchmarks (1.3.2)
      benchmark-ips (~> 2)
      get_process_mem (~> 0)
      heapy (~> 0)
      memory_profiler (~> 0)
      rack (>= 1)
      rake (> 10, < 13)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    devise (4.0.0)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    domain_name (0.5.20161129)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    eventmachine (1.0.9.1)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_girl (4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.0.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.0.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.7.2)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    faraday (0.11.0)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    figaro (1.1.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    flamegraph (0.9.5)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5.1)
    get_process_mem (0.2.1)
    gettext (3.1.7)
      locale (>= 2.0.5)
      text (>= 1.3.0)
    globalid (0.3.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    haml (4.0.7)
      tilt
    hashdiff (0.3.2)
    heapy (0.1.2)
    htmlentities (4.3.4)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    jquery-rails (4.1.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.6)
    kaminari (0.17.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    kgio (2.11.0)
    libv8 (3.16.14.17)
    locale (2.1.2)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.4)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4)
    mailcatcher (0.6.5)
      eventmachine (= 1.0.9.1)
      mail (~> 2.3)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      sinatra (~> 1.2)
      skinny (~> 0.2.3)
      sqlite3 (~> 1.3)
      thin (~> 1.5.0)
    memory_profiler (0.9.7)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
    minitest (5.10.1)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nokogiri (1.7.0.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.1.0)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    pg (0.18.4)
    public_suffix (2.0.5)
    rack (1.6.5)
    rack-mini-profiler (0.10.1)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-pjax (0.8.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (~> 1.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.7.1)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      actionview (= 4.2.7.1)
      activejob (= 4.2.7.1)
      activemodel (= 4.2.7.1)
      activerecord (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.7.1)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.8)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-erd (1.5.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2)
      activesupport (>= 3.2)
      choice (~> 0.2.0)
      ruby-graphviz (~> 1.2)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails4-autocomplete (1.1.1)
      rails (>= 3.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_admin (0.8.1)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0)
      font-awesome-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      haml (~> 4.0)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.14)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (~> 0.7)
      rails (~> 4.0)
      remotipart (~> 1.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0, < 6)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (4.2.7.1)
      actionpack (= 4.2.7.1)
      activesupport (= 4.2.7.1)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    raindrops (0.17.0)
    rake (11.3.0)
    redis (3.3.2)
    ref (2.0.0)
    remotipart (1.3.1)
    responders (2.3.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    rest-client (2.0.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    rest-client-logger (0.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.1)
      rest-client (>= 1.6)
    rspec (3.5.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-core (3.5.4)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-its (1.2.0)
      rspec-core (>= 3.0.0)
      rspec-expectations (>= 3.0.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.5.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-rails (3.5.2)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.5.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.5.0)
    rspec-sidekiq (2.2.0)
      rspec (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.0)
      sidekiq (>= 2.4.0)
    rspec-support (3.5.0)
    ruby-graphviz (1.2.2)
    rubyzip (1.1.7)
    safe_yaml (1.0.4)
    sass (3.4.23)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sentry-raven (0.15.6)
      faraday (>= 0.7.6)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    sidekiq (4.1.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.0)
      redis (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.1)
    simple_form (3.2.1)
      actionpack (> 4, < 5.1)
      activemodel (> 4, < 5.1)
    simplecov (0.12.0)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (>= 1.8, < 3)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.0)
    sinatra (1.4.7)
      rack (~> 1.5)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    skinny (0.2.4)
      eventmachine (~> 1.0.0)
      thin (>= 1.5, < 1.7)
    slim (3.0.6)
      temple (~> 0.7.3)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    spring (2.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13)
    stackprof (0.2.10)
    temple (0.7.7)
    text (1.3.1)
    therubyracer (0.12.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thin (1.5.1)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.19.4)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.5)
    translation (1.6)
      gettext (= 3.1.7)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.2)
    unicorn (5.1.0)
      kgio (~> 2.6)
      raindrops (~> 0.7)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    web-console (2.0.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
      binding_of_caller (>= 0.7.2)
      railties (~> 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
    webmock (2.3.2)
      addressable (>= 2.3.6)
      crack (>= 0.3.2)
      hashdiff
    will_paginate (3.1.0)
    will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.1)
      will_paginate (>= 3.0.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  annotate
  awesome_print (= 1.6.1)
  axlsx (= 2.1.0.pre)
  axlsx_rails
  bootstrap-sass (= 3.3.6)
  byebug
  chosen-rails
  codeclimate-test-reporter (~> 1.0.0)
  coffee-rails (= 4.1.0)
  database_cleaner
  derailed
  devise (= 4.0.0)
  dhis2!
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.0)
  faker
  figaro (= 1.1.1)
  flamegraph
  jquery-rails (= 4.1.1)
  jquery-ui-rails
  mailcatcher
  memory_profiler
  pg (= 0.18.4)
  rack-mini-profiler
  rails (= 4.2.7.1)
  rails-erd
  rails4-autocomplete
  rails_12factor (= 0.0.3)
  rails_admin (= 0.8.1)
  rest-client (= 2.0.0)
  rest-client-logger
  rspec-its
  rspec-rails (~> 3.0)
  rspec-sidekiq (~> 2.2.0)
  rubyzip (~> 1.1.0)
  sass-rails (= 5.0.6)
  sentry-raven (= 0.15.6)
  shoulda-matchers
  sidekiq (= 4.1.1)
  simple_form (= 3.2.1)
  simplecov
  sinatra
  slim (= 3.0.6)
  spring
  stackprof
  therubyracer (= 0.12.2)
  translation (= 1.6)
  uglifier (= 3.0.0)
  unicorn (= 5.1.0)
  web-console (= 2.0)
  webmock
  will_paginate (= 3.1.0)
  will_paginate-bootstrap (= 1.0.1)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.0p0

BUNDLED WITH
   1.13.7
```

Bundle install result:

```
Using rake 11.3.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.6
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 1.6.5
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.4
Using public_suffix 2.0.5
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using awesome_print 1.6.1
Using htmlentities 4.3.4
Using rubyzip 1.1.7
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using benchmark-ips 2.7.2
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using sass 3.4.23
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using choice 0.2.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using thor 0.19.4
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.4
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using docile 1.1.5
Using simplecov-html 0.10.0
Using connection_pool 2.2.1
Using safe_yaml 1.0.4
Using daemons 1.2.4
Using database_cleaner 1.5.3
Using get_process_mem 0.2.1
Using heapy 0.1.2
Using memory_profiler 0.9.7
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using unf_ext 0.0.7.2
Using netrc 0.11.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using eventmachine 1.0.9.1
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using flamegraph 0.9.5
Using locale 2.1.2
Using text 1.3.1
Using hashdiff 0.3.2
Using kgio 2.11.0
Using libv8 3.16.14.17
Using sqlite3 1.3.13
Using nested_form 0.3.2
Using pg 0.18.4
Using bundler 1.13.7
Using ruby-graphviz 1.2.2
Using rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
Using rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
Using remotipart 1.3.1
Using raindrops 0.17.0
Using redis 3.3.2
Using ref 2.0.0
Using rspec-support 3.5.0
Using temple 0.7.7
Using stackprof 0.2.10
Using will_paginate 3.1.0
Using faker 1.7.2
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.7.0.1
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using warden 1.2.6
Using rack-protection 1.5.3
Using rack-mini-profiler 0.10.1
Using mime-types 3.1
Using addressable 2.5.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 6.6.1
Using uglifier 3.0.0
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using figaro 1.1.1
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using haml 4.0.7
Using simplecov 0.12.0
Using crack 0.4.3
Using derailed_benchmarks 1.3.2
Using unf 0.1.4
Using thin 1.5.1
Using faraday 0.11.0
Using gettext 3.1.7
Using rails_12factor 0.0.3
Using unicorn 5.1.0
Using sidekiq 4.1.1
Using therubyracer 0.12.2
Using rspec-core 3.5.4
Using rspec-expectations 3.5.0
Using rspec-mocks 3.5.0
Using slim 3.0.6
Using will_paginate-bootstrap 1.0.1
Using activesupport 4.2.7.1
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using axlsx 2.1.0.pre
Using rack-pjax 0.8.0
Using sinatra 1.4.7
Using mail 2.6.4
Using bootstrap-sass 3.3.6
Using codeclimate-test-reporter 1.0.4
Using webmock 2.3.2
Using derailed 0.1.0
Using domain_name 0.5.20161129
Using skinny 0.2.4
Using sentry-raven 0.15.6
Using translation 1.6
Using rspec-its 1.2.0
Using rspec 3.5.0
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.7
Using activemodel 4.2.7.1
Using factory_girl 4.0.0
Using shoulda-matchers 3.1.1
Using spring 2.0.0
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using http-cookie 1.0.3
Using mailcatcher 0.6.5
Using rspec-sidekiq 2.2.0
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
Using activejob 4.2.7.1
Using activerecord 4.2.7.1
Using rest-client 2.0.0
Using actionview 4.2.7.1
Using annotate 2.7.1
Using rails-erd 1.5.0
Using dhis2 2.2.1 from git://github.com/BLSQ/dhis2.git (at master@d91e3eb)
Using actionpack 4.2.7.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.7.1
Using axlsx_rails 0.5.0
Using railties 4.2.7.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using kaminari 0.17.0
Using simple_form 3.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using responders 2.3.0
Using factory_girl_rails 4.0.0
Using font-awesome-rails 4.7.0.1
Using jquery-rails 4.1.1
Using jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5
Using rest-client-logger 0.0.1
Using rspec-rails 3.5.2
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Using rails 4.2.7.1
Using web-console 2.0.0
Using devise 4.0.0
Using chosen-rails 1.5.2
Using rails4-autocomplete 1.1.1
Using rails_admin 0.8.1
Bundle complete! 52 Gemfile dependencies, 150 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: Could you paste your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`? It's highly likely that you have some gem conflicts. Could you try running bundle install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

More than likely, the line in your Gemfile that includes the json gem looks like this:

```
gem 'json', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.3'
```

or something similar. This is telling rails that you want a specific version of the json gem and that the gem must be between version 2.0.3 and 2.1. The error you are getting indicates that rails is expecting an earlier version of the gem.

### Solution

Remove the version indicators so that the json line in your Gemfile looks like this:

```
gem 'json', '~> 1.8', '>= 1.8.6'
```

If that doesn't work, then simply try this:

```
gem 'json'
```

Don't forget to run `bundle install` after modifying your Gemfile!

Comment: thank you @Mark, now it works. What I did: I uninstalled all json version which was installed - included gem "json" in Gemfile and run "bundle install". Now it works perfectly

Comment: Hi hakif, I'm glad it worked for you! Would you mind accepting my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

The version required by the gemfile is json 1.8.6 which is older than json 2.0.2 which you already have, you can try this

```
gem 'json', '1.8.6'
```

Downgrade to json 1.8.6, might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ayush, I made it now I can run rspec. what I did: - I uninstalled all json version which was installed - included gem "json" in Gemfile and run "bundle install"